# android opengl es 1 - how do I apply glColor4f(r,g,b,a) to only one rendered object?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a GLSurfaceView on which I am drawing 3 squares. Now I would like to apply  glColor4f(r, g, b, a) to 2 of the 3 squares, and nothing to the third. I would like to end up with one square painted green, one painted red, and one with the original texture color (no color modification whatsoever).

Unfortunately, hen I apply glColor4f, it applies the color to everything on screen, not just the one square.

I tried using gl.glClearColor(r,g,b,a); and gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);. No success.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So... This was way easier than I thought:

after a given object is drawn, applying glColor4f(1,1,1,1) resets colors to bitmap texture default